# Switching between split views in VIM

Tags: vim

I'm having trouble switching between two views in Vim.

I'm using the Secure Shell Client, and every time I press `CTRL+W+W` to switch, the following lines are concatenated to the end of my code:

spell: Command not found

Thanks.

Best...SL

UPDATE:

Here's the result of the ":verbose nmap..." command suggested in the comments:

```
<C-W>        :w<CR>Go<Esc>:$r!spell %<CR>
             Last set from ~/.exrc
```

Comment: Sounds like something else is mapped to `<c-w>w`. You do a `:verbose nmap <c-w>w` to see what is being mapped and where.

Comment: See original post for results...

Comment: That's the answer to your problem: `CTRL-W` is mapped to something.  You can use `:nunmap <c-w>` to remove the mapping.

Comment: Once it's removed, how can I set it to switch between views? Thank you very much

Comment: You can use `<c-w>w` just like you were to switch views, after you unmap the `<c-w>`. There are more window mappings see `:h ctrl-w` for a list of them. You may be interested in `<c-w>h`, `<c-w>j`, `<c-w>k`, and `<c-w>l`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be permanent...is it?

Comment: If you want this to be permanent then it would be best to remove the `<c-w>` mapping from your `~/.exrc` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mapping in your `~/.exrc` file that is mapping the `<c-w>` key. It looks the mappings saves the file then puts the output of the spell command at the bottom of file. I would recommend you remove the `<c-w>` mapping from `~/.exrc` or remap it to something else like `<f8>`.

If you are worried about your spelling mapping you may want to look into vim's built in spelling. Set the following in your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set spelllang=en_us 
set spell
```

You can use `]s` and `[s` to more the next and previous misspelled words and use `z=` to get spelling suggestions. You can also use `<c-x>s` in insert mode to get spelling suggestions for the current word. For more about spelling see `:h spell`

For more help see:

```
:h exrc
:h vimrc-intro
```